# How to resolve promise in stream transform?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, stream, transform

How to resolve pending promises in the `addStuff` transform method? I tried wrapping in an async function and awaiting but that did not work. I assumed `stream/promises` would help, but still returns pending

```
const { pipeline } = require('stream/promises');
const JSONStream = require("JSONStream");

getStuff = async (id) => {
  const stuff = await axios.post('/get-stuff', {"id": id})
  return stuff
}

const addStuff = new Transform({
  writableObjectMode: true,
  transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    chunk.stuff = getStuff(chunk.id) // returns a pending promise, but i want stuff!
    this.push(JSON.stringify(chunk))
    callback()
  },
})

async function run() {
  await pipeline(
    fs.createReadStream(`./data/input.json`),
    JSONStream.parse('*'),
    addStuff,
    fs.createWriteStream(`./data/output.json`)
  );
  console.log('Pipeline succeeded.');
}

run().catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add `async` to transform and `await` getStuff

```
const addStuff = new Transform({
  writableObjectMode: true,
  async transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    chunk.stuff = await getStuff(chunk.id) // it gets stuff now
    this.push(JSON.stringify(chunk))
    callback()
  },
})
```